# How to have closer validation loss and training loss in training a CNN

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, training, convergence

I am using an AlexNet architecture as my Convolutional Neural Network.
A learning rate of 0.00007 and 128 batch_size.
I have 20000 data and 10% test, 40% validation, and 50% for training.
I used 100 epochs to train my network and here are my results for Loss and Accuracy.
I would like to ask how can I get closer validation and training loss in these plots?
At first, I guess the number of epochs was not enough, but I tried more epochs and my results didn't change.
Can I say my training process is complete with this distance between train and validation loss?
Is there any way to have closer loss plots?

[image]
[image]